# Nth derivative of $n^n$

Tags: calculus

I believe the limit derivative of $n^n$ is $n!$ where the limit derivative of a function is the derivative that will turn that function into a constant.

For polynomial functions, the limit derivative is the $m$th derivative where $m$ is the order of the function.

I discovered that for functioms of the form $n^c$ the limit derivative was $c!$ where $c$ was a known positive integer constant. Can someone prove or disprove this.

Comment: Your definition of limit derivative makes sense only for polynomial functions. Indeed, if some derivative is constant, then your function must be a polynomial.

Comment: Note that the derivative of $x^x$ is $x^x\ln x+x^x$.  If you start taking additional derivatives, this only becomes more complicated...

Comment: In case this is easy to prove and the question seems stupid, I'll have to apologise that my calculus skills are very insufficient(I'm incapable of integration and know only the barest of diffrentiation) due to stabbing calculs classes in high schools. I crammed for exams, and avoided the integration questions.

Comment: The derivative of $n^c$ where $c$ is any positive integer constant, was $c!$ for all c I tried.

Answer (score 3):

Since the derivative of $x^x$ is $x^x+x^x\ln x$,

- $\frac{d}{dx}x^x=x^x+x^x\ln x$.  Plugging in $x=1$ gives $1^1+1^1\ln(1)=1=1!$, so your formula works for the first derivative.
- $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^2=\frac{d}{dx}(x^x+x^x\ln x)=x^x+2x^x\ln x+x^x\ln^2x+x^{x-1}$.  Plugging in $x=2$ gives $2^2+2(2)^2\ln 2+2^2\ln^2(2)+2^1=6+8\ln 2+4\ln^2(2)$, which is not $2!$.  Therefore, your formula fails for $n=2$.

It is true, however, that

- $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}x^m=m!$ for all $m>0$.  The easiest proof is via induction where $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}x^m=m\frac{d^{m-1}}{dx^{m-1}}x^{m-1}=m(m-1)!=m!$.

Comment: My question is wrong it seems. I was thinking of functions in the form $n^c$. Which when taking the $c$th derivative turned out to be $c!$.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "the derivative that will turn that function into a constant".

Let

$$f^{(k)}=C.$$ Then by successive integrations,

$$f^{(k-1)}=Cx+C',$$

$$f^{(k-2)}=\frac12Cx^2+C'x+C'',$$
$$\cdots$$

Continuing this way, all you get are polynomials, which are the only functions with an eventually constant derivative, so your question has no answer.

By the way, finding a closed formula for the derivatives of $x^x$ looks somewhat hopeless.

[image]

Comment: Just a small joke : the monster can be simplified factoring out $x^{x-4}$ first. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Hi Claude. Who knows if it doesn't simplify in the end for a very high order... :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking for the derivative of the map, $f: \mathbb{R}_{+}^* \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x) = x^x = \exp(x\ln(x))$. You get :

\begin{equation*}
 f'(x)= x^x (\ln(x) + 1) \quad f''(x)= x^x \left(\frac{1}{x} + \ln(x) + 1\right) \; \cdots
\end{equation*}

The $n$-$th$ derivative of $f$ is never constant, because $f$ is not a polynomial function (it grows much faster than any polynomial)

Otherwise if you are considering only sequences, you can define the discrete derivative as follows. If $(u_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers, the discrete derivative of $u$, denoted by $\delta u$, is defined by $(\delta u)_n = u_{n+1} - u_n$. But even when using this definition, the limit derivative of $n^n$ is not defined properly, because the discrete derivatives of the sequence $(n^n)$ are never constants sequences...